# How we can impliment the combination of graphs (column-stacked) in StockChart with range seclector feature

Tags: highcharts

I have implemented the combination of graphs (column-stacked) in StockChart with range selector feature.

But the grouping is not correct for lower ranges like 24hour ,7 day.It is works when the range is above month.
In low ranges we got two type of bars one is with correct grouping and combination of graphs and other bars without any groupings.

How we can combine the graphs which works in all interwals.

Comment: Please, recreate issue on the jsFiddle, it really depends how you set this. In general, it simply works: http://jsfiddle.net/6xgy5d2f/

Comment: Thanks It is working on js fiddle.